# How to calculate metrics between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to calculate metrics between two tables? In addition, I noticed that when using `FROM tbl1, tbl2`, there are noises, the `WHERE` filters did not work, a total `count(*)` was returned

**Query:**

```
select
    count(*) filter(WHERE tb_get_gap.system in ('LINUX','UNIX')) as gaps,
    SUM(CAST(srvs AS INT)) filter(WHERE tb_getcountsrvs.type = 'LZ') as total,
    100 - (( gaps / total ) * 100)
FROM tb_get_gap, tb_getcountsrvs
```

**Error:**

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "gaps" does not exist
```

> I need to count in the `tb_get_gap` table by fields = `('LINUX', 'UNIX')`, then a `SUM ()`in the`srvs` field in the
>   `tb_getcountsrvs` table by fields = `'LZ'` in `type`, right after
>   making this formula `100 - ((gaps / total) * 100)`

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: but how would i compare?

Comment: If there is a smarter way, I'm open to suggestion, I'm not an SQL expert

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want implemented.

Comment: I'll reformulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you cannot define gaps and also use it in the same query. In SQL Server you would have to use the logic twice. Maybe a subquery would work better.

```
select 100 - (t.gaps / t.total) * 100)
from
(
select
    count(*) filter(WHERE tb_get_gap.system in ('LINUX','UNIX')) as gaps,
    SUM(CAST(srvs AS INT)) filter(WHERE tb_getcountsrvs.type = 'LZ') as total
FROM tb_get_gap, tb_getcountsrvs
) t
```

Comment: Desta forma funciona, mas note que os valores são inconsistentes

Comment: Maybe you can use a subquery?

Comment: I will check, tkss!

Comment: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Count in tb_get_gap.system = Linux, returns 2,050 alone, with subquery, returns 450,000

Comment: I don't understand why made noise in the subquery, any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to share your query / results.  I am not sure I understand what you mean.  The inner query should return 1 row, 2 columns only.  The count as Gaps, and the SUM as total.  If you run the inner query, is that what you get?   The outter query will just run your formula against the result.  I hope this helps.  One additional thing you can do is count a specific column instead of count(*)...   such as count(id)   (if you have an id field).  May be better for performance..  especially if you have tons of columns or big data columns. Good Luck

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the tip, I'm going to do some tests, but your answer already helps me a lot!